# Getting Django debug information when using Ajax call?

Tags: jquery, django

Is there a good way to get the debug information that Django provides when using jQuery to make Ajax calls?  Right now when I make a call, I just see a http/200 server error in the python runserver window, but because the call is made through javascript, I don't get a debug page with all the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inspect the contents of the response returned to your jQuery ajax call.   Using a tool like Firebug can make this pretty easy.

Django will still return the debug page, it's just that it is responding to the ajax call rather than a regular browser request.

It's often a good technique to get your stuff working with regular requests, and then "ajaxify" them only once you are sure the server side code is working.

Comment: What's annoying about that is it's all in unparsed HTML format. I guess I could just load it into a div...

Comment: Actually Firebug can open the returned HTML as a new tab in Firefox, so you can see it in the proper format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this snippet: http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/650/ to get plaintext tracebacks for viewing in firebug, instead of HTML.

Answer (score 1):

When you receive an AJAX error like that, you can replace your current document contents with the debug/error document returned from the server.  For example, you can do something like the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'failing_controller/',
    type: 'POST'
})
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        document.open();
        document.write(jqXHR.responseText);
        document.close();
    })
    .success(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // ... handle data ...
    });
```

This can be really helpful during development and debugging, because it lets you inspect the server state in real-time.  You will probably want to replace the failure handler with something more proper in a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way is to turn off debug, and rely on email debug messages Django sends. However, this isn't often practical, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try django_extensions + Werkzeug.