# Working with requests in Django debug mode gives unreadable info when erroring out

Tags: python, json, django, python-requests

I'm using the requests library inside of a Django management command to grab JSON data from another project of mine. In our development environment, both projects are running in debug mode, running in local runservers.

Normally I expect the view to return a JsonResponse. However, there's a syntax/import/whatever error taking place in the view that's receiving my POST request. If this request were taking place in the browser, I'd receive a big welcoming yellow page detailing my error tracebacks and other useful debug information. However, since this request is taking place in the requests library, what I get back is an unhelpful jumble of escaped HTML.

This HTML can be copied into an HTML file and reveal my error, that's a pain to do.

I was hoping that there's an easy way to have Django's debug mode return my error information in JSON rather than HTML so that I could read it right from the output of my management command. Ideally, it'd be smart enough to recognize if it came from requests.post vs a browser request (and return data appropriately) but I'm happy to toggle a setting if it gets me more useful debug info.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: So you want to disable the debug error page for xmlhttprequests / ajax  from django runserver? Do you use any third-party apps such as _django rest framework_ or _django-extensions_?

Comment: You might find some ideas in these threads. I don't think they are similar enough to this question to mark as duplicate.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593394/my-ajax-request-throws-an-error-in-django-how-do-i-find-what-it-is

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351889/getting-django-debug-information-when-using-ajax-call

Comment: The answers on the question that Bhargav posted to got me where I needed. Essentially, I have the option of making some middleware that sniffs out the user agent and returns the traceback in JSON instead (not nearly as hard as it sounds) or add a header to my POST request specifying headers={'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'}

I ended up going with the second option, and it's just what I was looking for!

Thanks for the answers everyone!